# How to read a text file that has float numbers to a float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, text, scanf

I have been trying to read a text file with the following:

```
0.000   1.800   3.240   4.374   5.249   5.905   6.377   7.696   6.887   6.974   6.974   6.904   6.778   6.609   6.406   6.177   5.930   5.670   5.403   5.133   4.863   4.596   4.333   5.077   3.829   4.589   3.360   3.140   2.931   2.732   2.543   2.365   2.198   2.040   1.891   1.752   1.622   1.500   1.387   1.281   1.182   1.091   2.006   0.927   0.853   0.786   0.723   0.665   0.611   0.561   0.515   0.473   0.434   0.398   0.365   0.335   0.307   0.281   0.257   0.236   0.216   1.197   0.180   0.165   0.151   0.138   0.126   0.115   0.105   0.096   0.088   0.080   0.073   0.067   0.061   1.055   0.051   0.046   0.042   0.038   0.035   0.032   0.029   0.026   0.024   0.022   0.020   0.018   0.017   0.015   0.014   0.012   0.011   0.010   0.009   0.009   0.008   0.007   1.006   0.006   0.005   0.005
```

This numbers are as formatted above in text file.

My code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#include <stdlib.h>

void main()

{

        FILE *file = fopen("Data.txt", "r");
        float integers[102];

        int i=0;
        int num;
        while(fscanf(file, "%f", &num) >0) {
            integers[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
        if( file == NULL )
         {
            printf("Error while opening the file.\n");

         }
        fclose(file);
        for(i = 0;i <102; i++){
        printf("integers[%d] = %f",i, integers[i]);
        }


}
```

The output of the `printf` is that all the elements in integers are zero when ran. Also when trying to debug I notice the compiler skips the while loop. I'm using Code Composer Studios.

Comment: Why do you call an array of floats "integers"? Why do you save the read integer in a `int`, not in a `float`? Why do you check for `null` very late?

Comment: Start testing if `fopen` returns `NULL` and if yes, print an error message and don't go any further.

Comment: @Zeta the code is not original, I had to modify it to make it read floats. The variables are from the original, did not change them.

Comment: @Zeta also i wanted to see if the while loop even read the file so i just  now notice why you said very late.

Comment: You display the "can't open file" error message AFTER attempting to read from the file. That's not what you should do.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I just modified the code, the print out statement IS  what is has at fopen.

Comment: @progy_rock just fixed that, and the compiler does execute the if statement.

Comment: Just edited the code to look as above.

Comment: @OscarTovar, nice try, but the test is too late, you must test `file` for `NULL` __before__ you use `file`. And it's not enough to print `"Error while opening the file.\n"`, you also must quit the program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz so i commented everything out from above code it looks like this now FILE *file = fopen("Oscar.txt", "r");
 if( file == NULL )
            {
               printf("Error while opening the file.\n");

            }

Comment: @MichaelWalz also it prints out the if statement. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @OscarTovar once the error message has been displayed the program should not continue trying to read from the file that could not be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach works as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  FILE * fp;
  float fval[102];
  int n, i;

  fp = fopen("foo.txt", "w+");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("failed to open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  fputs("0.000   1.800   3.240   4.374   5.249   5.905   6.377   7.696 ", fp);
  rewind(fp);

  n = 0;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%f", &fval[n++]) != EOF)
    ;

  /* n-1 float values were successfully read */
  for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    printf("fval[%d]=%f\n", i, fval[i]);

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
fval[0]=0.000000
fval[1]=1.800000
fval[2]=3.240000
fval[3]=4.374000
fval[4]=5.249000
fval[5]=5.905000
fval[6]=6.377000
fval[7]=7.696000
```

Comment: I did your code. did not see the foo text file where Data text file was(BTW the data came from matlab), searched it. Found it was at different file. The file was at the same level as Data text file. Move Data text file where foo text file was. Fixed the problem. You sir are a life saver. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I just modified the code to be a bit more terse and closer to what you were doing with the array. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head

```
    //int num;
    float num; // should be float isn't is
    while(fscanf(file, "%f", &num) >0) {
```

More

```
int main() // int main instead of void
{
    /* All declarations at one place */
    FILE *file = NULL; 
    float integers[102], num ;
    int i = 0;
    /* Try Open and exit if there is problem */ 
    file = fopen("Data.txt", "r");
    if( file == NULL ) {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /* Read and store EOF is always better */
    while( fscanf(file, "%f", &num) != EOF ) {
        integers[i++] = num;
    }
    /* Done with File Close it */
    fclose(file);
    /* Final Prints */
    for( i = 0; i < 102; i++ ){
        printf("integers[%d] = %.02f\n",i, integers[i]);
    }
    /* All success at this point */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Fixed the problem, still  have issues of a array with zeros for each element.

Comment: @OscarTovar I rolled back your question edit. You shouldn't edit the question in a way which makes answers invalid.

Comment: @hyde Sorry did not know. BTW how do you make this thread close, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -2):

Using vector we can slove the problem.See Below program.here myValues is 2D array.

ifstream input("Data.txt");
vector myValues;

for (float num; input >> num; )
    myValues.push_back(num);

or

ifstream input("my-file.txt");
std::vector myValues;

for (float f; input >> f; )
    myValues.push_back(f);